# Is there a checkstyle rule for forcing every field in a class to have an annotation?

Tags: checkstyle

We want to make compliance easy and for FedRAMP want something like this on all fields in our database objects

```
@FedRamp(confidentiality=LOW, integrity=MODERATE, availability=HIGH)
```

We want checkstyle to break the builds if people add data and forget to add these on 'any' field in the *Dbo.java class.  Then, we can generate the FedRAMP compliance on each data item (and therefore the entire system).  We run checkstyle on every class but only want this rule run on classes ending in *Dbo.java.  Is this possible where we import some already existing checkstyle rule or plugin and add the class name filter to it?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1):

To report violations for such cases for **any** classes, you can use [MatchXpathCheck](https://checkstyle.org/config_coding.html#MatchXpath) (you need checkstyle 8.39+)
Config will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
          "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<module name = "Checker">

    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="MatchXpath">
            <property name="id" value="fedramp_check"/>
            <property name="query" value="//CLASS_DEF/OBJBLOCK/VARIABLE_DEF/MODIFIERS/ANNOTATION/IDENT[not(@text='FedRamp')]"/>
            <message key="matchxpath.match"
                     value="Field should have 'FedRamp' annotation."/>
        </module>
    </module>
</module>
```

This will report violations like this:

```
$ cat Test.java
class Test {

 @FedRamp(confidentiality=LOW, integrity=MODERATE, availability=HIGH)
 private int withAnnotation = 11; // no violation

  @Fed(confidentiality=LOW, integrity=MODERATE, availability=HIGH)
 private int without = 11; // violation

  @NotNull
  int without = 11; // violation
}

$ java -jar checkstyle-8.42-all.jar -c config.xml Test.java
Starting audit...
[ERROR] C:\workdir\Test.java:6:4: Field should have FedRamp annotation. [fedramp_check]
[ERROR] C:\workdir\Test.java:9:4: Field should have FedRamp annotation. [fedramp_check]
Audit done.
Checkstyle ends with 2 errors.
```

Second part of your question - narrow execution only to specific classes - can be solved in several ways.

1. Use a bit different xpath to filter class names (not files, since there can be many classes in single file)

```
<property name="query"
   value="//CLASS_DEF[./IDENT[ends-with(@text,
   'Dbo')]]/OBJBLOCK/VARIABLE_DEF/MODIFIERS/ANNOTATION/IDENT[not(@text='FedRamp')]"/>
```

2. Use [BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter](https://checkstyle.org/config_filefilters.html#BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter) - it is filter for whole config and will work ok only if you have a separate config only for checking annotation thing.
3. Suppress violations for this check (by id, for example) for other class files, see [doc](https://checkstyle.org/config_filters.html#SuppressionFilter)

Comment: Good one. I didnt knew MatchXPath has this use.